# Avoid duplication of edges in roasal

Tags: pharo, moose-technology, roassal

Is there some way to avoid duplication of the edges in Roasal? I'm building a diagram of the meta-model form Moose, and I have some opposite relations but I don't have a reason to show them in both directions.

Comment: Please correct Roasal tag to Roassal